# How to diagnose why all threads in a ThreadPool are hanging on getting task from the queue?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

Our app is a high loaded server app. And sometimes we get into the situation where all threads in one of our pools are stuck. All the threads in `OperationExecutor` pool looks pretty the same:

```
"OperationExecutor/pool-8-thread-787" daemon prio=6 tid=0x00000000432cc800 nid=0x44ac waiting on condition [0x0000000037e3f000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x0000000548f585c8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

       Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None
```

*All of them* are waiting for the `<0x0000000548f585c8>` lock. Looks like they can not get the next task from the pool's queue. The queue is not empty (it's huge indeed) and the thread count is maximum allowed for the pool (this means the pool is doing maximum to digest the queue). We use a `LinkedBlockingQueue` as a pool's queue.

Here how's the pool is initialized:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(200, 200, THREAD_POOL_KEEPALIVE_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue(), new NamedThreadFactory(POOL_THREAD_NAME_PREFIX));
```

My single idea is that JVM has some problems with the `LinkedBlockingQueue`, but another part of me says it is not)

Can someone give a better idea why we're getting into this scrape?

Comment: Please post the code

Comment: Which one? We have dozens of places using this pool. This is an executor service of the app. We use `invokeAll()` and `submit()` to post tasks to this pool.